# The language of many buttons for kde applications (e.g. Konsole, kate, gimp) appear to be in Arabic

Tags: kubuntu, kde, konsole, kate

I have recently moved from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. When I use KDE as my desktop environment many of the buttons for applications appear to be in Arabic (I think - but could be another language I am unfamiliar with) - although I wanted English (UK or IrisApplications that have this problem include Konsole, Kate, Kile. It does not occur to LibreOffice apps, gimp. Under gnome, the fonts of all buttons are in English. I checked the regional settings but could not correct the problem. As I am fond of the KDE environment (have been using it for years) and apps like kile and kate are great for editing, I would really like to resolve the problem.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow as below:

1. System Settings → Locale
2. → Country tab: select country then apply
3. → Languages tab: add language and sort them then apply

**Reference:**

[System Settings/Locale/How To Install and Apply Interface Translation](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Locale/How_To_Install_and_Apply_Interface_Translation)